# How to convert .pcapng file(wireshark) data into .bin file

Tags: wireshark

I have wireshark data which is having Udplite packets. I am able to extract the required packets using range option in wireshark. Now I need to convert this entire
extracted packet set into single bin file , plus need to remove ethernet header from each packet.
Can anyone please help in this.

Comment: Wireshark has a [Lua API](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wsluarm_modules.html), so I'm not sure why you tagged this as C++? Alternatively, you could use libpcap to parse the pcap file, but then you still have to find/steal/borrow a "Udplite" dissector from somewhere.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  If you extracted the required packets using the range option in Wireshark, then presumably you have a new pcap or pcapng file containing only those packets, and both of those files are already binary files.  So what format of this bin file are you looking for exactly?  If you want to remove the Ethernet header, you can use `editcap` to cut the 1st 14 bytes from each packet (assuming no vlan tags), or you could use a tool such as Tracewrangler, but that only runs on Windows (or possibly in wine), so it may or may not be suitable for your use case.

Comment: Thanks ,just by saving .pcap file as .bin .i am getting the bin file.