# Converting pcapng file to bin format where the pcapng file has VITA49 content

Tags: matlab, pcap, bin

I'm trying to convert a .pcapng file that has VITA49.2 contents into a .bin file that is readable by the Matlab

Matlab example reading .bin file with VITA49 contents
https://www.mathworks.com/help//satcom/ug/vita-49-file-reader.html

This StackOverflow thread seems to indicate a solution being simply saving the pcapng file in Wireshark using a .bin file save option but that does not appear to be one of the Wireshark save options.
[How to convert .pcapng file(wireshark) data into .bin file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872760/how-to-convert-pcapng-filewireshark-data-into-bin-file)

Anyone have any comments on connecting the dots between pacapng and Matlab .bin for VITA49 files?